# Not able to use animation for a .png image

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to implement an animation on an image that enlarges the image by 10% till it's the original size (100%). Like it begins from a small size and it's top, left, bottom, right properties goes on increasing. (Hope it's understandable, otherwise, please comment)

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCtype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Interactive Webpage Practice - 1 </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle1.css"/>
        </head>
    <body>
        <span>
        <i> Your webpage is loading...</i><br>
        </span>
        <img src="welcome.png" alt="Lenny face"/>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

And the CSS code:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
}
span {
    margin-top: 10px;
    top: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(18, 149, 216);
}

img {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    -webkit-animation-name: welcome_visitor;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: welcome_visitor;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes  welcome_visitor {
    visibility: visible;
    0% {top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;}
    10% {top: 5px; left: 5px; bottom: 5px; right: 5px; }
    20% {top: 10px; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; }
    30% {top: 15px; left: 15px; bottom: 15px; right: 15px; }
    40% {top: 20px; left: 20px; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; }
    50% {top: 25px; left: 25px; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; }
    60% {top: 30px; left: 30px; bottom: 30px; right: 30px; }
    70% {top: 40px; left: 40px; bottom: 40px; right: 40px; }
    80% {top: 50px; left: 50px; bottom: 50px; right: 50px; }
    90% {top: 60px; left: 60px; bottom: 60px; right: 60px; }
    100% {top: 70px; left: 70px; bottom: 70px; right: 70px; }
}

@keyframes  welcome_visitor {
    visibility: visible;
    10% {top: 5px; left: 5px; bottom: 5px; right: 5px; }
    20% {top: 10px; left: 10px; bottom: 10px; right: 10px; }
    30% {top: 15px; left: 15px; bottom: 15px; right: 15px; }
    40% {top: 20px; left: 20px; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; }
    50% {top: 25px; left: 25px; bottom: 25px; right: 25px; }
    60% {top: 30px; left: 30px; bottom: 30px; right: 30px; }
    70% {top: 40px; left: 40px; bottom: 40px; right: 40px; }
    80% {top: 50px; left: 50px; bottom: 50px; right: 50px; }
    90% {top: 60px; left: 60px; bottom: 60px; right: 60px; }
    100% {top: 70px; left: 70px; bottom: 70px; right: 70px; }
}
```

[image: "image: welcome.png"]

^That's the image which is used in the HTML page.

Comment: why not just put it inside of a div, center it in the div on the x, y axis and then change the image size. to get the animation effect, use `transition: 0.5s; // or something like that`

Comment: But transitions requires a person to hover (or any other action) over the element so as to execute the change right? If it's an animation, it should start by itself without having to hover or require something from the visitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with two key factors:

1. `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` will keep the end state of the animation visible
2. `width: 0;` is required to define a starting point for the animation

```css
img {
  width: 0;
  animation: scaleUp linear 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
  to { width: 307px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVwzK.png"/>
```

If you really want to enforce the 10% increment between frames, you could use `steps()` instead of an easing function, but your animation will not be smooth:

```css
img {
  width: 0;
  animation: scaleUp steps(10) 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
  to { width: 307px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVwzK.png"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, the first solution worked. Actually, I had the idea of creating a smooth animation itself but couldn't figure out how to do that (quite a beginner in this). Oh and can I know why did you choose 307px as the width value? Like it could have been any number like 300 or 400 but why 307 specifically?

Comment: Also why isn't my animation working? Is there something wrong in the keyframes positioning values (top, left, bottom, right) I have entered?  Please point out the mistakes in the code due to which my animation did not work as expected. Will this work? :   `@-webkit-keyframes enlargeImg {
 from {top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;}
 to {top: 70px; left: 70px; bottom: 70px; right: 70px; }
}

@keyframes  enlargeImg {
 from {top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;}
 to { top: 70px; left: 70px; bottom: 70px; right: 70px; }`

Comment: `307px` is the native width of that image. Your animation is likely not working because your `img` and its parent need [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) set to something that isn't `static`.